# How to improve prediction performance of periodic data?

Tags: long-short-term-memory, prediction

I have a 1 column dataset of $50 000$ points where 95% of the values equal $-50$. The data looks like  the following: $$\begin{matrix}
\text{time} & \text{value}\\
1&-50 \\
2&-50 \\
3&-50 \\
4& -50 \\
5&3 \\
6&-50\\
7&-50\\
8&5 
\end{matrix}$$
As an addition, I know the exact time instance in which I will get value $\neq -50$ (as in the example above these are instances $5$ and $8$). The data is somewhat periodic, so the values which are different from $-50$ are chosen from a finite set $\mathcal{S}$.

To predict the values I use a 3 layer LSTM network with l2 regularizer where along with the values I input another column that looks like that:
$$\begin{matrix}
\text{time} & \text{value} & \text{expect a change}\\
1&-50 & 0 \\
2&-50 & 0\\
3&-50 & 0\\
4& -50 & 1\\
5&3 & 0\\
6&-50& 0\\
7&-50& 1\\
8&5 & 0 
\end{matrix}$$
which identifies the change one time instant in advance, so the LSTM will know to expect a change. However, the prediction performance is quite poor, it always predicts the change in the value but is far from real one and usually takes values out of the set $\mathcal{S}$. Any idea of how this could be improved?